# Wordpress+ASPxUploadControl asp.net on web.config error 404

Tags: c#, wordpress, web-config, permalinks, rules

my site is on shared Hosting.
I installed WordPress, then I copied with FTP the files of my asp.net project (c#).
For this I added rewrite rule on web.config:

```
     <rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
     <add input="{URL}" pattern="([a-zA-Z0-9\./_-]+)\.axd" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="None" />
     </rule>
```

But the ASPxUploadControl (DevExpress component for files upload) into my form "areariservata/scarica.aspx" didn't working.

So I modified web.config for this problem:

1. test:

```
   <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
   <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
   <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
   <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern=".axd$" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="None" />
   </rule>
```

2. test:

```
    <rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
     <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^areariservata.*" negate="true" />
     <add input="{URL}" pattern="([a-zA-Z0-9\./_-]+)\.axd" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="None" />
     </rule>
```

3. test:

```
    <rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
     <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="^areariservata.*" />
     <add input="{URL}" pattern="([a-zA-Z0-9\./_-]+)\.axd" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="None" />
     </rule>
```

Now AspxUploadControl works, but unfortunately I have an "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found" on navigate into WordPress pages.

So, how can I modify rule for navigate correctly on WordPress website (permalinks problem?) and make AspxUploadControl work?

Thanks for reply.